# Trouble installing django-imagekit - 'execfile' is not defined

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-imagekit

I am having problems installing django-imagekit under python 3.2/django 1.5. Is django-imagekit only for python 2 (then why is it available in pip-3.2)?

Trying to install django-imagekit from within my virtualenv.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/home/testuser/webapps/app/bin/pip run on Tue Nov 19 10:38:45 2013
Downloading/unpacking django-imagekit

  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-imagekit

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

      File "/home/testuser/webapps/app/build/django-imagekit/setup.py", line 25, in <module>

        execfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),

    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/home/testuser/webapps/app/build/django-imagekit/setup.py", line 25, in <module>

    execfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),

NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

----------------------------------------

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/testuser/webapps/app/build/django-imagekit

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/testuser/webapps/app/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/testuser/webapps/app/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/home/testuser/webapps/app/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg/pip/req.py", line 1009, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/home/testuser/webapps/app/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg/pip/req.py", line 225, in run_egg_info
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/home/testuser/webapps/app/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg/pip/req.py", line 225, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/home/testuser/webapps/app/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 256, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/testuser/webapps/app/build/django-imagekit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this module has been updated for python3 yet. Django has only officially supported python3 since 1.5, so several packages have yet to update.

Comment: We just pushed ImageKit 3.2 with Python 3 support! (1/1/2014)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of django-imagekit and, unfortunately, it isn't quite ready for Python 3 yet. As for why it's "available" for pip-3.2…My understanding is that pip doesn't do any filtering of packages based on the version of Python you're using; pip-3.2 is named that way because it installs packages into Python 3.2, but it doesn't use a separate index.

**EDIT:**

We just pushed ImageKit 3.2 which has support for Python 3! Give it a try (: